# Django 1.4 - Showing ImageField as a thumbnail in the admin page

Tags: django

How can i accomplish this ? I need to show an image rather the image url in Django Admin in the list display.

Anyone done this before ? Any help?

Been searching for the past hour without a solution, also I'm new to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-filer could be what you're looking for.

[image: Screenshot]

- Github: https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer/
- Docs: http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/

(Although I'm not sure whether this works in the list view too...)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i gace it a try but it didn't work with me. I keep getting an error when i click on the Folders links 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'root_path'

Comment: Yes i did, Django filer tables has been created. But each time I open the Folders Tab (added in Django Admin after Syncdb) i get the above error.

Comment: According to https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer/issues/173, this issue was fixed just recently. Install the current development version using `$ pip install -e git://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer.git#egg=django-filer`.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine :) Thanks a lot.